# saving appengine mail from spam filters

Tags: google-app-engine, email, spam

One of my clients uses Trend Micro InterScan Messaging Security to protect their internal mail services.

Suddenly InterScan decided to filter out all messages coming from Google App Engine.

Unfortunately they haven't been able to whitelist the sender address as each e-mail gets a different one. For example, `*3ckihSOVMMHlZHSL.JSMMHlZHSL.JS*@apphosting.bounces.google.com`, with everything before the `@` being variable.

**Update** I'm including this screenshot of how Interscan sees the incoming e-mail. Notice that all senders are different:

[image]

If I look into the e-mail headers, the apphosting domain appears inside the Return-Path field:

```
Return-Path: <36kSiSwYIBh0883XL3E7.5EH883XL3E7.5E@apphosting.bounces.google.com>
```

The "From" field looks ok. It says what I set it to say, but the spam filter only looks at the `Return-Path`.

My client sysadmin doesn't want to whitelist the whole `apphosting` domain, as it wouldn't be only whitelisting my application.

---

How could I bypass this e-mail filters if I can't get an unique sender?

Thanks,

Comment: You can't whitelist the domain?

Comment: how are you sending the mail?  with java or python, and with which API?  Are you sure you can't specify a consistent sender?

Comment: Adam - I'm trying for the client sysadmin to whitelist the domain. So far he's only offered to whitelist a full e-mail.

Comment: Peter - Python, the latest one. It is possible to specify a sender (in fact, I do it), but Trend Micro's filter is looking at another field that carries the apphosting domain - and it changes for every e-mail.

Comment: which specific field are they looking at?  Is there a reason they can't whitelist by some field under your control?  I can't imagine they blacklist the entire hotmail or aol domains, even though those must pump out a decent amount of spam.

Comment: Peter - I'm fairly sure that Hotmail pumps out an utterly indecent amount of spam.

Comment: It sounds to me like this is a Trend Micro/your client's admin problem. It seems like AppEngine mail is being pretty well-behaved.

Comment: Yes, I trust that Google must be doing the right thing, but it isn't enough for me in this case :(. I updated the original question with an image that shows how their software sees the e-mails. I hope there's a way to work with these corporate firewalls, as I need to cooperate with them for the e-mail service to be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the return-path header of mail sent by App Engine. The way I see it, you have two options:

- Whitelist everything from App Engine. Spam from App Engine is not a big problem, because it's expensive to send in the huge numbers spammers need, and we're constantly monitoring for spamming and shutting spammers down.
- Whitelist based on the X-Google-Appengine-App-Id header, which will be set to the app ID of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I am not well versed in spam filters, but it seems to me that if it can only whitelist based on one field, it is pretty lame.  Unfortunately that does not help you.  If this is an important client, and they absolutely refuse to budge, I see two possible paths forward:

- Do some research into interscan to see if you can give the client some pointers (tactfully) on how to configure it to whitelist in such a way that your mail can get through, but only your mail.
- Maintain a server outside app engine specifically for the purpose of sending emails.  You can build a super simple web app that just sends out emails, and call it from within your app engine app.